# OpenLDAP cannot import database configuration

Tags: debian, openldap, berkeley-db

I followed the quick-start guide of OpenLDAP in order to install it on Debian Jessie.

[Quick startupGuide](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html)

Everything went well, except that I am stuck at step 9. 
The command exposed doesn't work because the directory /usr/local/etc/cn=config doesn't exist. It is strange that they don't explain it needs to be created. Anyway, even when I create it, it sill doesn't work. I have another message : 
"**Available database(s) do not allow slapadd"**.

When I try a simpler command then in the quick startup guide, it fails as well : *slapadd -l /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.ldif* returns *slapadd: line 1: database #1 (dc=my-domain,dc=com) not configured to hold "cn=config"; did you mean to use database #0 (cn=config)?*

I modified the slapd.ldif to set my domain as : example.com, just like in the guide.

Something that could be important : when I typed in ./configure, something went wrong. Some BerkeleyDB libs were missing. So I installed the package libdb5.3-dev, then it worked.

It's been 3 hours I am struggling with that; I am really lost !

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: To make your installation and setup easier, you might want to consider installing the Debian packages that are already built and available from the usual Debian package repositories. While the jessie version is a bit old (2.4.40) it will be easier than installing from source.

Comment: Hello Rlandster. Thanks for the advice, but for the company needs, we need to install the last version. So it must be built from sources.Thanks anyway !

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Hitting the same problem.

Comment: Hello JonoCoetzee,
Unfortunately no. I skipped this step and I was able to launch ldap